# how to add parameter to url in typolinkwrap?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript

i use this code for displaying a link in a marker:

```
    $this->wrappedSubpartArray['###mMY_TEMPLATEMARKER###']=$this->cObj->typolinkWrap( array('parameter' => ($this->conf['single.']['pid'] > 0 ? $this->conf['single.']['pid'] : $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id), 'additionalParams' => '&' . $this->prefixId . '[show]=' . $rowArray[($this->piVars['pointer'] > 0 ? $this->piVars['pointer'] : 0)][$i]['uid'], 'useCacheHash' => 1) ); // Shows Detail Link
```

I would like to add the parameter

```
'&type=250'
```

in the end, but it just won´t show up or the & is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**What an ugly notation!!! :S**

Typolink takes additionalParams just as string `&param1=val1&param2=val` so just *glue* what you want into it (note that it **always** uses `&` char for params, even for first one):

```
$arr = array(
    'parameter' => ($this->conf['single.']['pid'] > 0 ? $this->conf['single.']['pid'] : $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id),
    'additionalParams' => '&' . $this->prefixId . '[show]=' . $rowArray[($this->piVars['pointer'] > 0 ? $this->piVars['pointer'] : 0)][$i]['uid'] . '&type=250', // <- here
    'useCacheHash' => 1);

$this->wrappedSubpartArray['###mMY_TEMPLATEMARKER###'] 
                          = $this->cObj->typolinkWrap($arr);
```

Comment: thanks and yes, i thought it is that easy too. however as soon the added parameter ist '&type=250' it is not displayed in the url: 'type=250' -> works; '&type=250'-> does not work; '&#34;type=250' -> works (which is strange, because the parameter before does not work)